# WordPress Multisite Network installation and dev questions

Tags: multisite

Please go easy on me. I'm a clutzy dinosaur. I currently have a large, unwieldy website hand-coded in html/css with php includes. It currently has a single WP installation in a subdirectory. The plan is to reorganize, and I want to use WP as the CMS and incorporate 3 WP blogs for 3 subdomains. Ideally, would like to create a WP multisite network to allow for further expansion and to save admin trouble.

I just want to confirm that if I install WP in the root directory and create 3 blogs (in subdomains), does this mean my website's home page is the mother blog's index.php? Essentially, I will have created 4 blogs - mother at root and 3 children in subdomains?

How to set this up on my Mac (OSX 10.5.8) running MAMP for development? And then how to migrate to server without breaking?

Answer (score 3):

#### WordPress Multisite is the way to go

WordPress Multisite is highly extensible and will even allow you to map full domain names to the subdomain blogs.  I just recently moved 15 client sites to 1 WordPress Multisite install and it went great.

There are some great Multisite resources over at wordpress.stackexchange.com

#### [Questions tagged with Multisite over at wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multisite)